# Calling JavaScript from Asp.Net CodeBehind(Not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, button, click

I need to know how can I call the below Javascript with a button click event in Asp.Net

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $("#various3").fancybox({
            'width': '75%',
            'height': '75%',
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'type': 'iframe'
        });
</script>
```

This is my normal Asp.Net button

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the code inside a function and call the function on client click event of the button.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function createFancyBox() {
    $("#various3").fancybox({
        'width': '75%',
        'height': '75%',
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'iframe'
    });
    // include this line to stop the button to call the server side event
    return false;
  }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return createFancyBox();" />
```

Comment: +1 but since the function will always return false and nothing ever will postback from the click of this button; i'd get rid of the `asp:button` control and just have a regular `button` element.

Comment: @Waqas-For button it dosen't work properly and If I use hyperlink it works well and what may be the reason for this?